# Java: Many-object variable ( static )

Tags: java, static

I am new to object oriented coding and I have the following problem.

(note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744824/java-class-variable-that-tracks-number-of-objects-instantiated) solution is part of my problem)

I need a variable that many objects can refer to, but keep some "private" information for each object. To be more specific, I created a class called `Worker` and I want every object of that class to have a unique ID of type `int`. So, first object has `ID=1`, second `ID=2` etc... Note that I don't want just a random integer, whereas I need to start counting from 0 and increment...

Declaration and initialization of the variable in the class

```
static private int workId = 0;
```

and I tried to implement incremention by adding this line of code in the constructor body

```
workId++;
```

I instantiate some objects, add them to an `ArrayList` and using a for loop I print each object's variables.

```
System.out.println("Worker ID: "+workerList.get(i).getWorkerId());
```

and `getWorkerId()` (class method) consists of

```
public int getWorkerId () { return this.workId; }
```

Problem is my programm won't print every unique `workID` (because there isn't), but the last value of the static variable (which happens to be the number of objects).

Can you describe a solution to my problem?

Comment: You're on the right track. Rename `workId` to `numWorkers`, then introduce another member, `private int id`. Then, change `workId++` to `id = ++numWorkers;` - This way, every worker has a unique ID, the static field simply keeps track of the number of IDs given out (or, in other words, the last ID that was assigned to a worker).

Comment: You might want to rename `workerId` to `workerCount` and add a new variable `workerId` and set the value of `workerId` in the constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comment turned answer:

**You're on the right track.**

Currently, your static member will be increased with every worker you create. This means it will not hold a worker's ID (this can't be the case, as a static variable belongs to the *class* instead of individual *instances*), instead it holds the *total number of workers* you created so far.

**Fix**

- Rename your static member to something like `numWorkers` so it reflects what it does
- Introduce another (non-static) member, `id` (or `workerId` if you prefer)
- Change `workId++` to `id = ++numWorkers`

**Why?**

Now, every worker has their own `id`. You assign it by looking at the current number of workers created (`numWorkers`), increment that value by one, then assign it to `id`. This way, your first worker's ID will be `1`, the second will be `2` and so on. `numWorkers` always holds the number of workers created, which is at the same time the last ID you handed out.

---

**Put together**

Since this question got quite some upvotes (= interest), I'll summarize the above into a blueprint:

```
public class Worker {
    private static int numWorkers; // Number of Worker objects created
    private int id;                // Individual ID of a worker

    public Worker() {
        id = ++numWorkers; // Will be 1 for the first, 2 for the second, ...
    }

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public static int getNumWorkers() {
        return numWorkers;
    }
}
```

Note that in Java, you don't need to initialize the [primitive type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) `int` to `0`, as that's the [default value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for an `int`. Of course, it is fine to do it anyway - it never hurts to be explicit.

Answer (score 4):

You are quite close to success actually.

Static members, as you may already know, belong to the class itself, not to each instance. But as you said, each worker should have his/her own unique ID, so `workId` should not be static.

However, we still need a static variable to keep track of what id should be given to the next worker we create. Let's declare one:

```
static private int nextWorkId = 0;
```

Then, in your constructor, you assign `nextWorkId` to `workId`, then increment `nextWorkId`:

```
workId = nextWorkId;
nextWorkId++;
```

You can also write it like this:

```
workId = nextWorkId++;
```