# Java constructor has to automatically generate and id value for the object

Tags: java

I've a question. I'm looking for idea for constructors which has to automatically generate an id value for the instances. I've searched many pages for that but I couldn't find the right idea. Maybe you have got any ways to do it ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds easy enough:

```
class MyClass {
    private int id;
    private static int numInstances;

    public MyClass() {
        id = ++numInstances;
    }
}
```

Also check out this related question/answer: [*Java: Many-object variable ( static )*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394634/java-many-object-variable-static/)

Comment: If `MyClass` is instantiated by multiple threads, you'll want to use an `AtomicInteger`.